# Updating existing field value in Reactive formArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In this situation when I am pressing the **Add** button, the item object(item object have item name quantity, etc) values are displayed the table below

[image]

during I am adding the items to the table, some times there will have same item names. in that case, I want to update only the quantity by checking the item name, if there no same item names then it will add a new row or it already has the item name in the table want to update the only quantity. below you can see my code.also add method is **dropDisplayValues()** and **credentials** is the form array group value.

```
this.purchaseOrderGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      categoryName: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [null, Validators.required],
      itemDetails: ['', Validators.required],
      itemName: [''],
      date: [''],
      itemId: [''],
      itemQty: [''],
      Avlqty: [''],
      supplierFirstName: ['', Validators.required],
      supplierLastName: ['', Validators.required],
      supplierId: ['', Validators.required],
      credentials: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    })


get f() {
return this.purchaseOrderGroup.controls;
}

dropDisplayValues() {

const itemId = this.f['itemId'].value;
const itemName = this.purchaseOrderGroup.controls['itemName'].value;
const qty = Number(this.f.quantity.value)
let AvlQty = this.f.Avlqty.value;
let final = AvlQty + qty;

if (qty !== 0 && itemId !== '' && itemName !== '') {

  const tableValue = this.formBuilder.group({
    itemId: this.f.itemId.value,
    itemName: this.f.itemName.value,
    qty: qty,
    status: 'Pending'
  });

  if(this.f.credentials.value!= undefined){

  this.f.credentials.value.forEach((data, index)=>{

    if(this.f.itemId.value == this.f.credentials.value[index].itemId){
      this.PushVaribaleCheck = this.f.credentials.value[index].itemName;
      const addValue = qty +this.f.credentials.value[index].qty;


     this.purchaseOrderGroup.controls['credentials'].patchValue([{qty:addValue}])

    }
  })
  if(tableValue.controls['itemName'].value !=  this.PushVaribaleCheck){
   this.phoneForms.push(tableValue);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a point to sort out the problem here what I have done, below is my code

```
  this.f.credentials.value.forEach((data, index)=>{

    if(this.f.itemId.value == this.f.credentials.value[index].itemId){
      this.PushVaribaleCheck = this.f.credentials.value[index].itemName;
      const addValue = qty +this.f.credentials.value[index].qty;

      const myForm = (<FormArray>this.purchaseOrderGroup.get("credentials")).at(index);
      myForm.patchValue({
        qty:addValue
      })

    }
  })
```

Comment: your value in this.f.credentials.value will always be a BLANK ARRAY. as I can not see you pushing any value in it. If this thing does not make sense according to you then please provide some running example as this is not much information.